# can't resize screen in chrome device mode

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to use chrome device mode on my linux machine, but opposite to my mac, it doesn't give me grid, nor black panel to choose device. It also doesn't have option to resize screen size, while on mac this options are present. I'm using chrome version 38. So it should all work, but unfortunately, it doesn't.

Sorry, can't post picture, as I need 10 reputation points.

Does any of you gone through this problem?

Cheers!